# Attribute introspection to get a variable in Objective-C

Tags: objective-c

Given a variable `id x` and a string `NSString *s` how can I get the instance attribute with name s for variable x?

ie. If we write `NSString *s=@"a"`, then we want `x.a`

Answer (score 15, accepted):

The [Objective-C Runtime Reference](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/objectivec/objective_c_runtime) lists

```
Ivar class_getInstanceVariable(Class cls, const char * name)
```

which returns an opaque type representing an instance variable in a class. You then pass that to

```
id object_getIvar(id object, Ivar ivar)
```

to get the actual instance variable. So you could say

```
#import <objc/runtime.h>

id getInstanceVariable(id x, NSString * s)
{
    Ivar ivar = class_getInstanceVariable([x class], [s UTF8String]);
    return object_getIvar(x, ivar);
}
```

if the instance variable is an object. However, if the instance variable is not an object, call

```
Ivar object_getInstanceVariable(id obj, const char * name, void ** outValue)
```

passing in a pointer to a variable of the right type. For example, if the instance variable is an int,

```
int num;
object_getInstanceVariable(x, [s UTF8String], (void**)&num);
```

will set `num` to the value of the integer instance variable.

Comment: Actually, object_getIvar takes an Ivar for the second argument.

Comment: Use Ivar class_getInstanceVariable(Class cls, const char* name) to get the Ivar to pass in

Comment: object_getInstanceVariable is not available in ARC mode

Answer (score 5):

Providing that `x` is key-value coding compliant for the `a` property, you can just do this:

```
id result = [x valueForKey:s]
```